# Removing the NavBar

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-navigation to navigate inside my app.
I have a screen (Login screen) in which I don't want the NavBar to show.
How can I remove it?

I tried using hideNavBar in the navigationOptions, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your StackNavigator, you need to set `headerMode` to `'none'`

Something like this

```
const ModalStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  Profile: {
    path: 'people/:name',
    screen: MyProfileScreen,
  },
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
);
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#StackNavigatorConfig